# JSP table doesn't show values from db

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

I'm a beginner in JSP and I'm trying to fill a table with some values from my database ! The values returned as a string which contains special characters and after a double split I try to pass the values to the table ! The problem is that even though I try nothing happens and my table stays empty , even though the methods return the correct values ! The problem might be in html but I can't find any solution to it ! Any ideas will be welcomed !

My code :

```
  <table id="seller_table" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>House id </th>
                    <th>Sell</th>
                    <th>Rent</th>
                    <th>Surface </th>
                    <th>Type of Building </th>
                    <th>Public Costs </th>
                    <th>Year of Build/Renovation </th>
                    <th>Type of Heat </th>
            </tr>
    <%

            String line;
            int counter=0;
            int i = 0;
            if(Souli.hoho()!=null){
            counter = 0 ;
            for(i=0;i<Souli.hoho().length();i++){
                if(Souli.hoho().charAt(i) == '$'){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            String[] lines = Souli.hoho().split("\\$");

            for(i=0;i<=counter-1;i++){

                line = lines[i];
                String[] kati = line.split("#"); 
    %>




            <tr>
                <td><%=kati[i]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[i+2]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[i+1]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[i+4]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[i+3]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[i+9]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[i+5]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[i+6]%></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
<%}}%>
```

Comment: Why don't you make simple `for (String line: lines) {...}` construction instead of 2 cycles? And why do you use `kati[i+2]` where `i` is index of `lines[]` array? Is that correct? `lines[]` and `kati[]` is different arrays.

Comment: I'm not aware of it could you give me an example ?

Comment: [Avoid using scriptlets.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<table id="seller_table" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>House id </th>
                    <th>Sell</th>
                    <th>Rent</th>
                    <th>Surface </th>
                    <th>Type of Building </th>
                    <th>Public Costs </th>
                    <th>Year of Build/Renovation </th>
                    <th>Type of Heat </th>
            </tr>
    <%

            //int i = 0; do you need i? I don't understand original structure
            if(Souli.hoho()!=null){
            String[] lines = Souli.hoho().split("\\$");

            for(String line: lines){
                String[] kati = line.split("#"); 
    %>




            <tr>
                <td><%=kati[0]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[2]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[1]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[4]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[3]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[9]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[5]%></td>
                <td><%=kati[6]%></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
<%}}%>
```

But I am not sure about indexes of `kati[]` array. Can you post original string example from database (before splits).
Also (if you still using this version) it's good idea to check how many elements in the `kati[]` array after splitting `line`. Is there exacly 10 elements?

Comment: this is the original string that comes from db 12#0#100000.0#house#100.0#1#autonomous#100#100#100$ 12#0#100000.0#house#100.0#1#autonomous#100#100#100

Comment: Seems like indexes in `kati[]` in my example correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting special character in `kati` array then you can use tab library and use

`c:out` as

```
<c:out value=${yourArrayvalue} escapeXml='true'/>
```

so you will get desired output

Comment: kati contains only strings without special characters